# AWS Connect and Lex - How to reference a value of a slot from lex excution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have a Lex bot where it collects a value for a slot "name".
Then in the lex interface, for fulfillment, I selected "return parameters to client", I assume this means it will return intent and slot values to Connect when I add a "get customer input" from lex block in Amazon Connect?
Then I want to check if the value from the slot is equal to a certain name, so I used "check user attributes" block, but things seem not working properly.
Is it the way that I reference the slot value wrong? I used "$.Lex.slots.name"
Please point out if my understanding is wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$.Lex.Slots.<slotName>` with a capital `S`.  So it would be `$.Lex.Slots.name` for your example.